# Trying to create a alert in sql and looking for tips in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, alert

Trying to setup sql query in Oracle SQL and need help with condition

- Table Involved: 1. Orders
- Fields in Orders: 1. Order_No 2. Order_Status

Condition: If more than 50% orders are loaded on truck and one order is at least not allocated then return the record.

Comment: What do you mean by "an alert"? How do you expect to be alerted? Why do you think you can get an alert in SQL? Where does the truck appear in your table? How does an order get allocated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to

- create a stored procedure which checks that table for conditions you mentioned
- if conditions are met, send an e-mail (using `UTL_MAIL` package)
- schedule that procedure to run regularly; you should know how often - is it once a day (night job is usually used in such cases), every hour, ... You'd use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to do that

Comment: I have updated the question. Just looking to get the condition

Comment: _"Just looking to get the condition"_   We don't know your data. We don't know what indicates "the condition".  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example